# how to fix game image on taller devices

Tags: image, graphics, libgdx

I made and finish a game for android using libgdx with a virtual width and height of 320 x 480. my problem is on different resolution. I don't have an artistic talent so I don't have an idea what to do with this.
I set my camera like this

```
this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
this.camera.setToOrtho(false, 320, 480);
```

I have this two screenshot, I used the libgdx sample image for simplicity.

on this first screenshot 
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAjxX.png)

using `config.useImmersiveMode = false;`

where I design my game. everything is perfect. as you can see the square image is drawn perfectly.

on this second screenshot [stretch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtr69.png)

using the `config.useImmersiveMode = true;`

the image is stretch, on my game all the game art are stretch which is it so ugly to look at. I don't have an idea of what to do to achieve the right solution.

as you game developers what is your approach to this problem? flappy bird works well with different devices

Comment: Viewports handle this for you. Also unless you really want pixel perfect rendering I advice against using screen resolution as the camera units. Use meaningful units. A lot of beginners go wrong by doing everything with pixels, your game does not need to know pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stretching you can calculate and set camera zoom, based on screen dimensions. That way some part of play field will be cut out if device screen is in different proportions, but at least you won't loose correct aspect ration.